# Error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException in back-end developing of an ecommerce

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, backend, e-commerce

I'm trying to develop the back-end for an e-commerce in Spring boot. I have problems when I try to add a product to the cart. Here are the entities and the relations between them:
[image]

(The relation between Product and ProductInCart is 1:n, the relation between  Cart and ProductInCart is 1:n and the relation between Cart and User is 1:1).

When I try to add a product into the cart the following error is thrown:

> ERROR 7088 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]
> : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with
> path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception
> is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException:
> Type definition error: [simple type, class
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested
> exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
> serializer found for class
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no
> properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
> disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
> chain:
> com.ptoject.demo.entities.Product$HibernateProxy$cD4I8n6B["hibernateLazyInitializer"])]
> with root cause
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
> serializer found for class
> org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no
> properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
> disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
> chain:
> com.ptoject.demo.entities.Product$HibernateProxy$cD4I8n6B["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
> ...

ProductRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

    List<Product> findByNameContaining(String name);

    Product findByBarCode(String barCode);

    List<Product> findByCategory(String category);

    @Query("select p from Product p where p.price >= ?1 and p.price <= ?2")
    List<Product> findProductsByPriceInRange(float minPrice, float maxPrice);

    @Query("select p from Product p where p.price >= ?1")
    List<Product> findProductsByMinPrice(float minPrice);

    @Query("select p from Product p where p.price <= ?1")
    List<Product> findProductsByMaxPrice(float maxPrice);

    boolean existsByBarCode (String barCode);
}
```

ProductInCartRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductInCartRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductInCart, Integer> {
}
```

CartRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Integer> {

    Cart findByBuyer(User buyer);
    
    @Query("select c from Cart c where c.buyer.id = ?1 ")
    Cart findByUserId(int userId);

    @Query("select c from Cart c where c.order = ?1 ")
    Cart trovaCarrelloDaOrdine(Order order);

}
```

UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    List<User> findByLastName(String lastName);

    User findByEmail(String email);

    List<User> findByCode(String code);

    List<User> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
    boolean existsById(int id);

}
```

ProductService:

```
@Service
public class ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductInCartRepository productInCartRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addProduct(Product product) throws BarCodeAlreadyExistsException, ProductWithoutBarCodeException {//
        if(product.getBarCode()!=null && productRepository.existsByBarCode(product.getBarCode())){
            
            throw new BarCodeAlreadyExistsException();
        }
        if(product.getBarCode() == null || product.getBarCode()==""){
            throw new ProductWithoutBarCodeException();
        }
        productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void removeProduct(Product product) throws InexistentProductException{//

        if(!productRepository.existsById(product.getId()) || (product.getBarCode()!=null && !productRepository.existsByBarCode(product.getBarCode()))){
            
            throw new InexistentProductException();//il barcode deve essere necessarianette presente
        }
        productRepository.delete(product);

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Product addToCart (int productId, int userId, int quantity) throws ProductUnavailableException {
        System.out.println("UserId: "+userId);
        System.out.println("PeoductId: "+productId);
        System.out.println("Quantity: "+quantity);
        if(userRepository.existsById(userId)){
            System.out.println("Exists");}
        User user = userRepository.getById(userId);

        Product product = productRepository.getById(productId);
        System.out.println("Product: "+product);
        Cart c = user.getCart();
        List<ProductInCart> pc = c.getProductsInCart();
        ProductInCart p = new ProductInCart();
        p.setProduct(product);
        p.setCart(c);
        p.setQuantity(quantity);
        ProductInCart justAdded = productInCartRepository.save(p);
        entityManager.refresh(justAdded);
        Product pr = justAdded.getProduct();
        int newQuantity = pr.getQuantity() - p.getQuantity();
        if (newQuantity < 0) {
            p.setCart(null);
            productInCartRepository.delete(p);
            throw new ProductUnavailableException(pr);
        }
        entityManager.refresh(p);
    return pr;

    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Product> showAllProducts(){//
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }//

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Product> showAllPaginedProducts(int pageNumber, int pageSize, String sortBy){//
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy));
        Page<Product> pagedResult = productRepository.findAll(paging);
        if(pagedResult.hasContent()){
            return pagedResult.getContent();
        } else {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)//
    public List<Product> showProductsByName(String name){
        return productRepository.findByNameContaining(name);
    }


    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Product> showProductsByCategory(String category){//
        return productRepository.findByCategory(category);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)//
    public Product showProductsByBarCode(String barCode){//

        return productRepository.findByBarCode(barCode);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)//
    public List<Product> showProductsByPriceInRange(float minPrice, float maxPrice) throws CostWrongRangeException{
        if(minPrice>maxPrice){
            throw new CostWrongRangeException();
        }
        return productRepository.findProductsByPriceInRange(minPrice, maxPrice);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Product> showProductsByMinPrice(float minPrice){//
        return productRepository.findProductsByMinPrice(minPrice);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Product> showProductsByMaxPrice(float maxPrice){//
        return productRepository.findProductsByMaxPrice(maxPrice);
    }

}
```

When

```
if(userRepository.existsById(userId)){
            System.out.println("Exists");}
```

is executed, it prints

> "Exists"

UserService:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public User addUser (User user) throws MailUserAlreadyExistsException {//
        if(user.getEmail()!=null && userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())){
            throw new MailUserAlreadyExistsException();
        }

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void removeUser (User user) throws MailUserDoesNotExistException {//
        System.out.println("User: "+user);
        if(!userRepository.existsById(user.getId()) || user.getEmail()!=null && !userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())){

            throw new MailUserDoesNotExistException();
        }

        userRepository.delete(user);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User loginUser (User user) throws UserNotFoundException{
        if(user==null || !userRepository.existsById(user.getId())){

            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }

        return userRepository.getById(user.getId());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }//

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> getByNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName){//
        return userRepository.findByFirstNameAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User getByEmail(String email){
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }//


}
```

CartService:

```
    @Service
    public class CartService {
    
        @Autowired
        private CartRepository cartRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        private ProductInCartRepository productInCartRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    
    
        @Transactional(readOnly = false)
        public Cart addProductInCart (Cart cart) throws ProductUnavailableException, EmptyCartException{//
    
            if(cart.getProductsInCart()==null || cart.getProductsInCart().size()<=0){
                System.out.println("Empty cart");
                throw new EmptyCartException();
            }
            Cart result = cartRepository.save(cart);
    
            for(ProductInCart pic: result.getProductsInCart()){
                pic.setCart(result);
                ProductInCart justAdded=productInCartRepository.save(pic);
                entityManager.refresh(justAdded);
                Product product= justAdded.getProduct();
                int newQuantity = product.getQuantity()-pic.getQuantity();
                if(newQuantity<0){
                    cartRepository.delete(cart);
                    pic.setCart(null);
                    productInCartRepository.delete(pic);
                    throw new ProductUnavailableException(product);
                }
    
                entityManager.refresh(pic);
            }
            entityManager.refresh(result);
            return result;
    
        }

 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Cart getCartByUser(int user) throws UserNotFoundException{//
        if(!userRepository.existsById(user)){
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }
        return cartRepository.findByUserId(user);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Cart getCartByOrder(Order order) throws OrderNotFoundException {//
        System.out.println("CART SERVICE. Id order: "+order.getId()+", id cart: "+order.getCart().getId());
        if(!orderRepository.existsById(order.getId())){
            throw new OrderNotFoundException();
        }
        if(cartRepository.trovaCarrelloDaOrdine(order)==null){
            System.out.println("NULLLLL");
        }
        return cartRepository.trovaCarrelloDaOrdine(order);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Cart> getAllCarts(){
        return cartRepository.findAll();
    }//

}
```

ProductController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @PostMapping ("/createProduct")
    public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody @Valid Product product){
        try {
            productService.addProduct(product);
        } catch (BarCodeAlreadyExistsException e) {
           
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Barcode already exists!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            //ResponseEntity is a generic type. Consequently, we can use any type as the response body.
            
        } catch (ProductWithoutBarCodeException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Product without barCode!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Addedd successfully!"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/removeProduct/{product}")
    public ResponseEntity remove(@PathVariable("product") Product product){
        try{
            productService.removeProduct(product);
        }catch (InexistentProductException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("The product does not exist!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseMessage("Removed successfully."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/addProduct")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<Product> addProductToCart(@RequestParam(required = false) int productId,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) int userId,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) int quantity){
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(productService.addToCart(productId, userId, quantity), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (ProductUnavailableException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseMessage("The quantity of product: "+e.getProduct().getName()+" is unavailable!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping ("/getAllProducts")
    public List<Product> getAll(){
        return productService.showAllProducts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/paged")
    public ResponseEntity getAll(@RequestParam(value = "pageNumber", defaultValue = "0") int pageNumber,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", defaultValue = "10") int pageSize,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", defaultValue = "id") String sortBy){

        List<Product> result = productService.showAllPaginedProducts(pageNumber, pageSize, sortBy);
        if(result.size()<=0){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("No results!"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchProduct/by_name")
    public ResponseEntity getByName(@RequestParam(required = false) String name){//funziona
        List<Product> result = productService.showProductsByName(name);
        if(result.size()<=0){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("No results!"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchProduct/by_category")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getByCategory(@RequestParam(required=false) String category){//funziona
        List<Product> result = productService.showProductsByCategory(category);
        if(result.size()<=0){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchProduct/by_barcode")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getByBarcode(@RequestParam(required = false) String barCode){//funziona
        Product result = productService.showProductsByBarCode(barCode);
        if(result==null){
            return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseMessage("No results!"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{minPriceProduct}/{maxPriceProduct}")
    public ResponseEntity getProductsByPriceInRange(@Valid @PathVariable("minPriceProduct") float minPriceProduct,
                                            @PathVariable("maxPriceProduct") float maxPriceProduct ){
        try {
            List<Product> result = productService.showProductsByPriceInRange(minPriceProduct, maxPriceProduct);
            if(result.size()<=0){
                return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("No resultsts!"), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(CostWrongRangeException e){
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Min price must be less than max price!", e);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/minPriceProduct/{minPriceProduct}")
    public ResponseEntity getProductsByMinPrice(@Valid @PathVariable("minPriceProduct") float minPriceProduct){
        List<Product> result = productService.showProductsByMinPrice(minPriceProduct);
        if(result.size()<=0){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("No results!"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/maxPriceProduct/{maxPriceProduct}")
    public ResponseEntity getProductsByMaxPrice(@Valid @PathVariable("maxPriceProduct") float maxPriceProduct){
        List<Product> result = productService.showProductsByMaxPrice(maxPriceProduct);
        if(result.size()<=0){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("No results!"), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/reg")
    public ResponseEntity<User> create(@RequestBody @Valid User user){
        try {
            User added = userService.addUser(user);
            return new ResponseEntity(added, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (MailUserAlreadyExistsException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseMessage("ERROR: Email already exists."), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }


    }

    @DeleteMapping("/removeUser/{user}")
    public ResponseEntity remove(@PathVariable("user") User user){

        try {
            userService.removeUser(user);
        } catch (MailUserDoesNotExistException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("ERROR: Email does not exist."), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("User successfully deleted."), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity loginUser(@RequestParam(required=false) User user){
        try{
            userService.loginUser(user);
        }catch (UserNotFoundException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("ERROR: User does not exist."), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("You are logged in!"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAllUsers")
    public List<User> getAll(){
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userFirstName}/{userLastName}")
    public ResponseEntity getUsersByFirstNameAndLastName(@Valid @PathVariable("userFirstName") String firstName,
                                                         @PathVariable("userLastName") String lastName){
        List<User> result = userService.getByNameAndLastName(firstName, lastName);
        if(result.size() <= 0){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("No results."), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchUser/by_email")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUsersByEmail(@RequestParam(required = false) String email){
        User result = userService.getByEmail(email);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

CartController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/carts")
public class CartController {
    @Autowired
    private CartService cartService;

    @PostMapping("/createCart")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody @Valid Cart cart){
        System.out.println("Cart in cartController: "+cart);
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(cartService.addProductInCart(cart), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (ProductUnavailableException e) {

            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("The quantity of product: "+e.getProduct().getName()+" is unavailable!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (EmptyCartException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Empty cart."), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);

        }
    }
@GetMapping("/cart_by_user")
    public Cart getCartByUser(@RequestParam(required = false) int user){
        try {

            return cartService.getCartByUser(user);
        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "User not found!", e);
        }
    }


    @GetMapping("/cart_by_order/{cartOfOrder}")
    public ResponseEntity getCartByOrder(@Valid @PathVariable("cartOfOrder") Order order){
        //if(order==null) {
            System.out.println("Id order from cartController: "+order.getId()+" cart id: "+order.getCart().getId());
        //}
        try {
            Cart result = cartService.getCartByOrder(order);
            if(result == null){
                return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("No results."), HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (OrderNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Order not found!", e);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAllCarts")
    public List<Cart> getAll(){

        return cartService.getAllCarts();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `findById` instead of `getById`.

Comment: I tried, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: If that doesn't fix it you either didn't replace al `getById` or `getXXX` methods by `findByXX`. The `get` will create a lazy proxy whilst the find will actually do a database call (depending on your version of Spring Data in use it will return an `Optional`. It should at least change the error you get as you don't get a proxy anymore, unless there is more you aren't showing us.

Comment: Thanks, I changed all the getByXXX with findByXXX and now it works!